# How to use one class in jquery to php/html foreach loop?

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas

My title is quite confusing but my question is..

is have this script plugin wherein the plugin will create a bubble-like progress bar found [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Customizable-Liquid-Bubble-Chart-With-jQuery-Canvas.html).

in the script I have `$('.demo').waterbubble();`

now have a foreach loop that is..

```
<?php foreach($bins as $binArray): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($binArray as $bin):?>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <canvas class="demo"></canvas>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

so in this code it should iterate the canvas and display bubbles depending on the `$bin` variable. I tested with 6 iterations so it should show 6 bubbles, but instead it only shows one bubble and the others are not showing any bubbles. I inspect the code and the `<canvas class="demo"></canvas>` is iterated properly but not showing anything for some reason. Any one knows why is that? and is there any way to use this or to work around this? thank you very much!

Comment: give them each a unque id, and call waterbubble for each

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it's an issue with the script. You might be better off trying to init each waterbubble with a unique ID.

```
<?php foreach($bins as $binArray): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($binArray as $bin):?>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <canvas id="demo<?= $bin[number] ?>"></canvas>
      </div>
      <script>
        $('#demo<?= $bin[number] ?>').waterbubble();
      </script>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: and then `$('#demo1').waterbubble({txt: 'Default',});
$('#demo2').waterbubble({waterColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',txt: 'jQuery'});
$('#demo3').waterbubble({txt: '50%',});` etc

Comment: This is a good one. It works but I feel like i am 'hacking' into it just to make it work? Im using cake php so my scripts are on the top like      `<?php
$scriptBlock = <<<JS
$(".demo<?= $bin->id ?>").each(function() {
    waterbubble();
});
JS;
$this->Html->scriptBlock($scriptBlock, ['block' => true]);
?>` and my php/html are below this. Any idea how i could pass the `$bin` variable from the foreach loop to the script above?

Comment: @jeeeee I don't know, personally...not familiar with CakePHP. Where does that scriptBlock get output onto the page?

Comment: well, i'm still new to it too but to explain what i mean is. How can i do the same loop to `$bins as $binArray` then `$binArray as $bin` in the script so that i could get the value of $bin[number] and use it.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention the two loops I realize my example probably doesn't work properly as it'll output the same IDs multiple times as it looks through `$bins`.